# How do I process the value that I get from a form and use that value to give a result

Tags: python, jquery, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to make a quiz app which allows users to answer questions and get their scores back,the questions are stored on a database. I'm having problems with getting the scores back, when I click submit to answer the question I get an AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'score'

I searched to see if someone did something similar and I got the idea to use jquery to get the userid and the value that the user input

This is my html page to display the questions and multiplechoices:

```
<head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='jquery.js') }}">\x3C/script>')</script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scoring.js') }}"></script>


        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css">
        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    </style>
    <!-- Required for the page -->
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        //sets the global variable to the prefix to the root of the application
        $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
        //Calls the answer checking script with the variable argument
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select').material_select();
            $(".button-collapse").sideNav(); 
            startScript({{ current_user.id }}, {{ users[0].score }});
        });
    </script>

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>



        <body>
            <h5 class="center-align">Answer the Questions</h5>
            <form action="http://localhost:5000/info" method='POST'>
                {{ form.csrf_token }}


                    {% for computersystemsq in computersystemsq %}
                    {% for computersystemsm in computersystemsm %}

                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col s12">
                                    {{ computersystemsq.question }}
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="{{ computersystemsm.id }}"></div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col s6">
                                        A: {{ computersystemsm.wrong_answer1 }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col s6">
                                        B: {{ computersystemsm.wrong_answer2 }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col s6">
                                        C: {{ computersystemsm.answer }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                            <div class="input-field col s6">
                                                {{ form.options( class= computersystemsm.id ) }}
                                                <label for="options">Select an Option:</label>                  
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" id="{{ computersystemsm.id }}">mark</button>
                <br>
                        </div>  
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
```

This is the scoring code to give the user the score and store this score back into the database:

```
function startScript( current_userId) {
    $( document ).ready( readyFunction );

    function readyFunction() {
        $("button").click( function(event) {
            var url = $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/info';


            var selectedId = $(this).attr('id');
            var selectedValue = $("select." + selectedId).val();
            $.getJSON( url, {
                id: selectedId,
                value: selectedValue,
                user_id: current_userId
                },
                function (data) {
                    //Doing the checking and all on server side
                    var scoreElement = document.getElementById("studentusersscore");
                    scoreElement.text = 'Your SCORE is ' + data.score;
                    $("." + selectedId).hide(1000);

                }
            );
            event.preventDefault();



        });
    }
}
```

This the url for getting the score back and storing it back in the user's table:

```
@app.route("/info",methods=['POST'])
def info():
    id = request.args.get('id',0,type=int)
    value = request.args.get('value',0,type=str)
    userId = request.args.get('user_id',0,type=int)


    presentUser = User.query.get( userId )
    presentScore = presentUser.score
    computersystemsm=ComputerSystemsMultipleChoices.query.filter( ComputerSystemsMultipleChoices.id == id ).all()

    if computersystems[0].answer==value:
        presentScore=presentScore + 1
        presentUser.score=presentScore
        correct=1

    else:
        presentScore=presentScore -1
        presentUser.score=presentScore
        correct=0

    return jsonify(score = presentScore, correct = correct)
```

Traceback:

```
AttributeError
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'score'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "c:\users\dami\envs\compsci\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "c:\users\dami\envs\compsci\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "c:\users\dami\envs\compsci\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "c:\users\dami\envs\compsci\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "c:\users\dami\envs\compsci\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "c:\users\dami\envs\compsci\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "c:\users\dami\envs\compsci\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "c:\users\dami\envs\compsci\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "c:\users\dami\envs\compsci\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
        self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
        try:
            request_started.send(self)
            rv = self.preprocess_request()
            if rv is None:
                rv = self.dispatch_request()
        except Exception as e:
            rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
        return self.finalize_request(rv)

    def finalize_request(self, rv, from_error_handler=False):
File "c:\users\dami\envs\compsci\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
        # request came with the OPTIONS method, reply automatically
        if getattr(rule, 'provide_automatic_options', False) \
           and req.method == 'OPTIONS':
            return self.make_default_options_response()
        # otherwise dispatch to the handler for that endpoint
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

    def full_dispatch_request(self):
        """Dispatches the request and on top of that performs request
        pre and postprocessing as well as HTTP exception catching and
        error handling.
File "C:\Users\Dami\dev\compsci\revision_website\quiz.py", line 358, in info
presentScore = presentUser.score
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'score'
```

Overall what I want to happen is that the user score should be returned to them for each question and that score should be added to the table to be stored for each question they get right or wrong.

Comment: any ideas? really need the help

Comment: now I've figured out how to submit the answer but I'm now getting a different error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'score'

Comment: I'd start by looking carefully at the stack. Something is being asked for its score when it is actually None. My guess is `users[0].score`. Are you passing `users` into `render_template()`? Does it have at least one item in it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm following this code: https://github.com/suhithr/Quiz-Engine/blob/master/app.py . I don't really think I understand what he's doing to get the User Id, score and answer tbh in his fetch_answer def

Comment: His code works, though. :-) What does the stack say?

Comment: oh wow, that's so annoying I'm literally doing everythin he's doing. When I do the method on his quiz.html and don't put ajax script src at the bottom of the page the button doesn't work and I get nothing back. When I do add the ajax at the bottom of the page, I get the error. I try returning userId to see what's being returned and I got 0 back

Comment: Can you please provide the stack? It should be the first place you look when trying to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: wait, what do you mean by stack?

Comment: It's the list of stack frames you get when an error is thrown. Have a look at [this article](http://cs.franklin.edu/~ansaria/traceback.html) and then read your stack trace/traceback/stack/backtrace (all different names for the same thing).

Comment: ok thanks, I'm still not really sure so I've edited the post and posted the traceback

Comment: Ah hah, so the second to last line tells you exactly where the problem is: `presentScore = presentUser.score`. So presentUser is null, meaning `presentUser = User.query.get( userId )` returned nothing. What is the value of `userId` when this failure occurs?

Comment: right, when I tried to return userId I got back 0 and I don't know why because there is a user logged in

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. `current_user` should be available in your jinja2 templates. Are you able to access it from outside the template? Have you tried logging in with other users to make sure it's not an issue with one particular user? What happens when you add a `@login_required` decorator to the '/info/' route?

Comment: When I added  @login required I got back this error:Unauthorized
The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested. You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required. Then I took it out and tried to return current_user.id and I got this error: AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'id'. So I don't really know how to remove the user from anonymous

Comment: The problem is that you aren't successfully signing in. That's why the user doesn't have an id. Why do you think you've signed in successfully?

Comment: because I get redirected to the correct page after logging in. I feel like I get logged out when I try to submit the answer of the quiz I don't know why